# HTML5 video in Rails App not fully watchable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, video, html5-video

I have an HTML5 video loaded using rails but only 14 seconds of the video is watchable and then the video stops and you can't go to any part of the video past 14 seconds, which is only about 25% into the video.

Here is the code in my `index.html.erb`

```
<%= video_tag @video.filename + ".mp4", :size => "320x240", :controls => true %>
```

And here is my controller:

```
def index
  @video = Video.last
end
```

If you click the download button on the HTML5 video control panel, it downloads the video and it is fully watchable, so it isn't the file that's causing the problem, plus I know this same video works perfectly fine in HTML5 video tags in another PHP-based app I have, so I'm pretty sure the problem is being caused by rails somehow but I have no idea how.

Also, not sure if this is relevant but even though the video won't go past 14 seconds (25%), the darkened bar that indicates the video is buffered extends all the way to about 75% of the way through the video.

**Update:** I just tried another video and that video was at least fully watchable but still the timeline on the HTML5 video control does not work, you can't skip to any part of the video or go back to any part of the video, you can only watch the video in the order you're supposed to and restart it from the beginning. Is rails just incapable of handling HTML5 videos properly?

Could it have something to do with rails rendering the tag as `<video controls="controls">` instead of just `<video controls>`?

**Update 2:** I looked at the source and opened the video in another window, which the browser displays by using an HTML5 player. I tried this with both videos and it fixes one of them, but not the other one. The first video I mentioned still is not navigable and still stops at 14 seconds, the second video however, works perfectly fine and is navigable.

Comment: can you share the videos? I'd hazard a guess that there's something off in the encoding which is causing the failure...

Comment: Have you tested in multiple browsers? Different browsers have different levels of support for video and audio encoding. You can also check the encoding using `ffprobe` which is part of the `ffmpeg` tool set. One last option, upload it to YouTube, make sure it works, then download it and try that file.

Comment: I'm fairly certain it has nothing to do with the encoding because I've tried it using several different MP4's all encoded differently and none of them work properly. In Mozilla however, the video are navigable up until the point they're buffered to, but on chrome they don't really work at all, some of them only play until about 20 seconds in. There seems to be absolutely no consistency whatsoever in how a video works between different videos but every individual video plays the same every time. However, almost none of them work as they should. I really have absolutely no idea what do to.

Comment: Have to do another comment due to character limit. This problem seems like it should be something simple to fix, or at least something other people have encountered. I think I might have to just use something other than the HTML5 video player because I can't get rails to work with it at all.

Comment: This problem ended up being due to rails being bad at serving video files in a way that allows them to be played properly. Uploading the videos elsewhere and linking to them via url makes them all work normally.